# jQuery Syntax Help

Tags: jquery, ajax, syntax

Sorry for asking such a newbie question, I know it makes a few of you here angry. But I think learning the syntax is the hardest part so don't flame me too badly.

Right, I'm using the Tabs widget from the jQuery UI. I'm stuck with setting the options for this. This is how it stands...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#forumswitch").tabs({
        event: 'mouseover',
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I'm using Ajax with this however I want it to be cached instead of requesting new data each time a tab is changed. (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cache)

How would I add this to the settings? I know it's done with arrays but I seem to mess it up every time I try.

Comment: this has nothing to do with syntax

Comment: I didn't know the syntax to impliment this. I knew what needed to be there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument being sent to [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) is a hash/associative array of options. Just add `cache: true` to this hash.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#forumswitch").tabs({
        event: 'mouseover',
        cache: true
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems obvious now. I thought you needed "sub-array" for ajax options. Seems not. Thanks again.

Comment: Evan, please take away the comma behind the "cache:true", it may cause error in many javascript engines

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#forumswitch").tabs({
        event: 'mouseover',
        cache: true
    });
}); 
</script>
```